# Bash iterate over each line and run a command utilizing the first word and second word of each line

Tags: bash

I have a function that parses a file and got it down to the following output which is stored in a variable

```
option1 value1
option2 value2
option3 value3
etc...
```

I need to loop through each line and run a command that uses both values on each line. Something like the following is what I'm thinking

```
for each line in "$var"; do
    command "$first_word $second_word"
done
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is quite on-point.

Comment: BTW, see http://shellcheck.net/ for automated checking -- as it is, you're currently missing a great deal of quoting. And there's no need to have your edits say what you edited -- questions' edit history is available for anyone who needs it to review.

Comment: ...as another aside, `command` is actually a [real POSIX-specified command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/command.html) built into the shell. To avoid confusion, then, it's typically better to use a stub that wouldn't otherwise exist like `yourcommand`, `mycommand`, etc. as a placeholder, or something demonstrative like `printf 'First word: <%s>, second word: <%s>\n' "$first_word" "$second_word"`.

Comment: Good points. Sorry I was writing quick and dirty. Bad move. My mistake. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), a `while read` loop is the appropriate tool for the job:

```
while read -r first_word second_word rest; do
  your_command "$first_word" "$second_word"
done <<<"$var"
```

Note the use of `rest` -- having a placeholder (`_` is also common) means that words after the second one are not also placed in the `second_word` variable.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Worked perfectly.